# Nested entity and API endpoints for a custom extension

Tags: api, extension

I am working on an extension and I want a particular API endpoint structure. I'm trying to have this structure:

[image]

Based on the documentation [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/step-by-step/create-entity/), having entities created as direct children to the `v3` or `v4` directory and creating CRUD operations on those is pretty straight forward and you get most of the work done for you using civix:

[image]

**Question:** Is there a way to create nested entities and api endpoints so that I can create the api structure in the first image?

When I created the `Certification` entity, the generated files shown in the second image support top level CRUD functionality (Ex: Certification -> Create), but not (Ex: Certification -> Math -> Skill -> Create). This is probably because of the generated BAO and DAO classes being like `CRM_Certification_BAO_Certification` and the `base` element in `Certification.xml` being `CRM/Certification`. I am sure there are other conflicts too that I am missing.

So far I have tried this code for my `Read.php` endpoint under the `Certification->Math->CompletedSkill` path:

[image]

The code does not execute / API not called

Note: As I mentioned above, I can get the API call to work if I make a file directly under `Certification` and call it something like `Getmathcompletedskills.php` and change the code to:

[image: ![enter image description here]